# How to pcap dropped packets with PointToPointHelper in NS3

Tags: networking, simulation, pcap, ns-3

I was trying to capture the packets in NS3 experiment.

I used **PointToPointHelper** to use pcap.
And, it can capture the normal packets.

```
PointToPointHelper pointToPoint;
pointToPoint.EnablePcap ("Host", (hosts.Get(0))->GetDevice(1));
```

But, it cannot capture the packet that I intentionally dropped.

I dropped the packets in RouteInput method.
And I just simply **return false** to drop the packet.

```
RouteInput(Ptr<Packet> p, Ipv4Header &header, Ptr<const NetDevice> idev, UnicastForwardCallback ucb, MulticastForwardCallback mcb, LocalDeliverCallback lcb, ErrorCallback ecb) {
...
return false;
}
```

And I found that pcap didn't capture the dropped packets.

Although, the packet was intentionally dropped by the switch, it did come to the switch. So, I want the packet be capture by pcap.

Is there a way that I can capture the packets that is intentionally dropped?

Answer (score 0):

if not work with pcap file, NS3 generate also a .tr file with d operation, which means a packet was dropped.